Velocity to put into relativistic doppler effect with expansion of universe
It is well known that there are few kinds of redshifts (e.g. relativistic, cosmological, gravitational).
And the formulas are
\begin{align}
1+z_\mathrm{rel}&=\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}\,\,\text{(for completely radial direction)}\\
1+z_\mathrm{cos}&=\frac{a_\mathrm{now}}{a_\mathrm{then}}
\end{align} for relativistic and cosmological, respectively.

However, when two effects are mixed, it confuses me which parameter will go into $v$ for relativistic doppler effect.
Since the proper velocity in cosmology $v$ is addition of Hubble flow and peculiar velocity, i.e. $v=v_\mathrm{pec}+Hd$, where the $d$ is proper distance, I don't know what to put into the formula.

Is the peculiar velocity $v_\mathrm{pec}$ is the parameter for $z_\mathrm{rel}$? Or just $v$ ?

Just compose the two, $1+z=(1+z_\mathrm{rel})(1+z_\mathrm{cos})$, where $z_\mathrm{rel}$ is evaluated using the peculiar velocity.
Both of these contributions can be interpreted as kinematic Doppler shifts due to the relative velocity between source and receiver; the $(1+z_\mathrm{rel})$ factor accounts for the peculiar velocity while the $(1+z_\mathrm{cos})$ factor accounts for the Hubble flow velocity. So if you were to include the Hubble flow velocity in calculating $z_\mathrm{rel}$, then you would improperly double-count it.
Alternatively, it would be correct in principle to forget $z_\mathrm{cos}$ and compute the total redshift $z$ as the kinematic Doppler shift $z_\mathrm{rel}$ associated with a total relative velocity $v$ that includes both the peculiar velocity and the Hubble flow (see e.g. this paper). However, that $v$ is not what you have written, i.e., $v\neq v_\mathrm{pec}+Hd$. The quantity $Hd$ is not even a relative velocity in the relativistic sense of corresponding to an angle in spacetime. Additionally, velocities in relativity do not add linearly.
